# use of the "in" type guard in typescript

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I am trying to create a type guard - to allow typesafe conversion of a series of shorthand css properties, to their longhand version - but do so without having to cast the rule back to `keyof SxProps` at the end.

```js
type SxProps = { w?: string; width?: string; h?: string; height?: string; }
const shorthandCssRuleMapping = {
  w: 'width',
  h: 'height'
} as const;

export function hasKey<K extends string>(
  key: K,
  object: {}
): object is { [_ in K]: {} } {
  return typeof object === "object" && object !== null && key in object;
}

export function convertShorthandRule(rule: keyof SxProps) {
  let longHandRule = rule;
  if (hasKey(rule, shorthandCssRuleMapping)) {
    let pickedShortHandRule = shorthandCssRuleMapping[rule];
    // @NOTE: REALLY wish we didn't have to cast here...
    longHandRule = pickedShortHandRule as keyof SxProps;
  }
  return longHandRule;
}
```

basically, the type of pickedShorthandRule is this: `{} | "width" | "height"` before we cast it. Im pretty sure this is from a dodgy type predicate - but cant work out how to fix it. :P

I really need it to be: `"width" | "height"` - so that I can get rid of the cast: `as keyof SxProps`

Help!

Comment: A few things to fix here. Firstly, `typeof null === "object" so you need to test for this possibility. Secondly, `hasKey` is somewhat has a problematic type signature as it will make properties with keys not in the type, the instantiation of `K`, unavailable within the scope of the guard.

Comment: Aha! ofcourse. Fixed the above to check for null. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `object is { [_ in K]: {} }` to `object is { [_ in K]: keyof SxProps }` to make sure the values in `shorthandCssRuleMapping` will be always from long-hand keys

```
type SxProps = { w?: string; width?: string; h?: string; height?: string; }
const shorthandCssRuleMapping = {
  w: 'width',
  h: 'height'
} as const;

export function hasKey<K extends string>(
  key: K,
  object: {}
): object is { [_ in K]: keyof SxProps } {
  return typeof object === "object" && object !== null && key in object;
}

export function convertShorthandRule(rule: keyof SxProps) {
  let longHandRule = rule;
  if (hasKey(rule, shorthandCssRuleMapping)) {
    let pickedShortHandRule = shorthandCssRuleMapping[rule];
    longHandRule = pickedShortHandRule;
  }
  return longHandRule;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygHgBQE4HswGcoF4oG8oDuA-AFxTrBICWAdgOYDchVAJsABanmW2NSdkK1ek3YQqddsC5DeTAL4BYAFABjFDQrl2KJBwCGNFgGF06AEoBXADYQAsvrBhe2PCqiEyAcgKsOXgBp3fm8xCSkvFXkofUx1TWAGFRUIODBdYCgAM0saVWAqDX5YgGkIEAAeEqhU4AgjTFl6AD4ACmCAa3KyEqDlDxQAIwArCHyyXCVlAEoyIdH8qCpMfABtAH0lmigSgF0yLpAULNhEVAwoaNxgpAhgSyRt0EhjqHmxzKwvqAAid-yflAAGRAt4jD5QACE3xoNmswNBhy2YIWiSiyWUqXSemyuXyhW28QAbhA9DAdHp2IYWFZbK0kDYIAdyq94Mg0Ohpm5%20lBbJlrBo6AAJam06A4Bm2JI8qgnVpU9BlED0xkBbQZKlGUwWRkOJy8aZc648jx8qDOVRdFjkjIioxi1zoCkGLVmMV65z0VaSiC7aUeU2Cu00xmuC1Wm16YNi-2XG53B7bAX0aOM6XyIA)